# How to load template file when Word add-in starts

Tags: javascript, ms-word, ms-office, add-in, office-js

I'm using the JavaScript API for Office v1.1 to create a Word add-in, and I would like to replace the document by loading a template file. It seems that the only option is to convert the file to base64. Is there a more feasible option?

Comment: What would be 'more feasible' to you? If base64 is already working, is there a particular reason that it is not suitable for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options are to use the `insertFileFromBase64` method or you could also insert a piece of OOXML using the `insertOoxml` method.

You can find details about both at:https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/word/body